How do I calculate the impact force on a piston full of air?
I am working on a project for a highschool physics class in which we do an egg drop(in this case meaning dropping an egg from about 5.7m and trying to make it not break). My partner has decided to use one of those plastic syringes (without the needle) to act as a spring. I have been tasked with calculating the impulse on the egg. To do that I need the net force on the syringe piston to calculate the time it takes to compress. I have the pressure on the inside of the syringe (I used $Pv=nRT$). The problem is I can't figure how to do the external force. So far I have tried calculating impact pressure then converting it to force:
$$
P_{imp} = \frac{\rho V_i^2}{2}
\\
F_{imp} = \pi r^2 P_{imp}
$$
Where $\rho$ is gas density, $V_i$ is the impact velocity and $r$ is the radius of the syringe. I was able to calculate net force etc. with this but I am getting really weird spikes in the program I wrote, specifically when the plunger reaches the bottom which shouldn't be able to happen in the first place. I am not sure if this is do to my trash code or an error in my math. Any help would be much appreciated.
Edit: This is a calculator that I programmed that is sort of working.

The edit is an improvement but few things are still unclear (to me): 1. What exactly is the "egg drop" experiment in your case? For example, sometimes the goal is to build an apparatus that prevents the egg from breaking, at other times, we just want to measure some aspect of the impact, etc. Please clarify. 2. When you mention "weird spikes" what are you referring to? Do you have the syringe somehow hooked up to a digital monitor or something like that?

Also, see if this related question helps

Friction between the rubber plunger and the plastic cylinder is far from negligible in those things. You might want to measure that.

@SolomonSlow, this doesn't need to be super exact as we just need to show our work. We will also be lubricating it so it should be pretty minimal. It is a good thing to note though.
